# GridView Row Within Javascript OnClick Event ASP.NET C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am struggling to get my "Copy To Clipboard" code fully working.  Right now I can manually type in the row index but then it is hard coded so it will only copy the row specific no matter which one I click on.  I have a GridView with the following ASP.NET OnClientClick event in it.  Where I am having the issue is with the "MainContent_GridViewTickets_txtCopyToClipboard1_0".  I need to be able to set that last "0" to the row index dynamically.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lblTrailer1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Trailer1") %>' OnClientClick="clipboardData.setData('Text', document.getElementById('MainContent_GridViewTickets_txtCopyToClipboard1_0').value);"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get row index after click action on client side. For instance,

```
  <script type = "text/javascript">
     function GetSelectedRow(lnk) {
         var row = lnk.parentNode.parentNode;
         var rowIndex = row.rowIndex - 1;

         return rowIndex;
     }
  </script>
           <ItemTemplate>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSelect" runat="server" Text="Select" CommandName = "Select" OnClientClick = "return GetSelectedRow(this)" />
              </ItemTemplate>
```

In your case: document.getElementById('MainContent_GridViewTickets_txtCopyToClipboard1_' + GetSelectedRow(this))

Comment: This was it!  Great answer and easy to follow.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Container` is GridviewRow coming in row context as IDataContainer.

you can use it find what another control that located in same row..

```
<asp:LinkButton 
ID="lblTrailer1" 
runat="server" 
Text='<%# Bind("Trailer1") %>' 
OnClientClick='clipboardData.setData("Text", document.getElementById("<%#((GridViewRow)Container).FindControl("txtCopyToClipboard1").ClientID%>").value);'>
</asp:LinkButton>
```